# How to use an array loop in pgSQL

Tags: arrays, postgresql, plpgsql

I want to do something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ff(int, text) RETRUNS integer AS $$
DECLARE
    r text;
BEGIN
    FOR r IN SELECT string_to_array($2, ',')
    LOOP
        INSERT INTO test(i, t) VALUES($1, r);
    END LOOP;
    RETRUN 0;
END
$$LANGUAGE pgsql;
```

I hope that the function `SELECT ff(3, 'a,b');` does

```
INSERT INTO test(i, t) VALUES(3, 'a'); 
INSERT INTO test(i, t) VALUES(3, 'b');
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You don't need a loop for that, you could use [`unnest`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-array.html#ARRAY-FUNCTIONS-TABLE) to convert the array from `string_to_array` into a set of rows and then use a simple `insert ... select` construct:

```
create or replace function ff(int, text) returns integer as $$
begin
    insert into test(i, t)
    select $1, s 
    from unnest(string_to_array($2, ',')) as dt(s);
    return 0;
end
$$ language plpgsql;
```

I've also corrected some typos (`RETRUNS`, `RETRUN`, and `pgsql`) along the way.

You could also use [`regexp_split_to_table`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER):

```
create or replace function ff(int, text) returns integer as $$
begin
    insert into test(i, t)
    select $1, s
    from regexp_split_to_table($2, ',') as dt(s);
    return 0;
end
$$ language plpgsql;
```

If you're stuck in the 8.1 stone age and can't do anything about it, then perhaps something like this would work:

```
create or replace function ff(int, text) returns integer as $$
declare
    a text[]; 
    i int;
begin
    select string_to_array($2, ',') into a; 
    i := 1;
    loop  
        if i > array_upper(a, 1) then
            exit;
        else
            insert into test(i, t) values($1, a[i]);
            i := i + 1;
        end if;
    end loop;                                 
    return 0;       
end
$$ language plpgsql;
```

I think that should work in 8.1 but I don't have access to 8.1 to check.

Comment: I got: function unnest(text[]) does not exist. function regexp_split_to_table(text, unknow) does not exist. my postgresql version is 8.1.2

Comment: There is no need for plpgsql here, so sql function can be used instead. Returning a constant will also be useless, so the function can `returns void`. What is that `dt(s)` ?

Comment: @Leajon: 8.1? You need to upgrade ASAP, 8.1 passed its end of life awhile ago so it gets no more bug fixes or security patches.

Comment: @user272735: `dt(s)` is the table alias with a column name. And we can't know if the `return 0` is useless or not with more context, there could be all sorts of good reasons for this function to return zero.

Comment: @Leajon: I just added a version that should work with 8.1, the choice of version might be out of your hands.

Answer (score 12):

Since PostgreSQL 9.1 you can use FOREACH LOOP to iterate over an array. An example from [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html):

```
CREATE FUNCTION sum(int[]) RETURNS int8 AS $$
DECLARE
  s int8 := 0;
  x int;
BEGIN
  FOREACH x IN ARRAY $1
  LOOP
    s := s + x;
  END LOOP;
  RETURN s;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

For you, [mu's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12102860/1801588) is better, but most users who find this question by its title would prefer my answer.